# Why doesn't becomeFirstResponder trigger soft keyboard on alert message textField

Tags: swift, xcode, uialertcontroller, iphone-softkeyboard

I have an UIAlertController with a `textField` showing on my app. The `textField` is selected (the marker is blinking in it) and `.becomeFirstResponder` is set on the `textField`. But for some reason, the `soft-keyboard` isn't showing. I printed a boolean `isFirstResponder` and it returned `false`.

I read somewhere that it has to be trigged in `viewDidLoad`, but that's not possible in this case since the alert is shown by pressing a `button` from a `function` that is outside of `viewDidLoad`

Here's my code:

```
func verificationPopup(title: String, message: String, codeShouldBeVerified: Bool, context: UIViewController, callback: @escaping() -> Void) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    //THIS IS THE RELEVANT PART
    if(codeShouldBeVerified) {
        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { textField in
            textField.placeholder = "Fyra siffror"
            textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
            textField.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
            textField.becomeFirstResponder()
            print("HERE", textField.isFirstResponder)
        })
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Jag fick ingen kod", style: .default, handler: { action in
            callback()
        }))

    }
    else {
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
            callback()
            //self.verifyNumber()
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Avbryt", style: .cancel, handler: {
            action in
            print("CAAAANCEL")
        }))
    }
    context.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Seems odd that `.isFirstResponder` returns false when I just set it. What's going on here?

Comment: why don't we make `becomeFirstResponder` after adding the action to alert?

Comment: You have this already checked probably, but I remember when I had similar problems and just failed to see the obvious for quite a long time... So just to make sure: There are circumstances when it's normal that the soft keyboard won't come up. (a) when there's a Bluetooth keyboard attached to a real device, or (b) when a hardware keyboard is being simulated in the device simulator (menu: Hardware->Keyboard->Connect Hardware Keyboard). Make sure this is not the case here...

Comment: @Lutz Ah, that was it! Thanks a lot. Such an obvious thing to miss. I knew about it, but didn't think it worked in this way. Anyway, thanks again. Write a real answer and I'll be happy to check it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are circumstances when it's normal that the soft keyboard won't come up.

(a) when there's a Bluetooth keyboard attached to a real device, or

(b) when a hardware keyboard is being simulated in the device simulator (menu: Hardware->Keyboard->Connect Hardware Keyboard).

I know this for a long time and still sometimes it happens to me that I get confused why the keyboard won't come up until I remember to check (mostly when using the simulator). It's easy to miss so make sure that this is not the case here.